# Permutations of list in Python without shifted arrangement

Tags: python, permutation

So, let's say I had a list: [1, 2, 3]

The permutations of such a list would be [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], and [3, 2, 1]

(Group 1) However, let's say we look at the arrangement [1, 2, 3]. If we shift it over by one, we get [3, 1, 2]. Do this again, and we get [2, 3, 1].

(Group 2) If we look at the arrangement [1, 3, 2] and shift it over by one, we get [2, 1, 3]. One more and we get [3, 2, 1].

Both of these arrangement groups make up the permutations of the list.

My questions is if this can be utilized to make a faster permutation generator than permutations from itertools.

I do not mind which list arrangement I get for each group, but I would like to decrease the time spent generating permutations.

(Note: I understand this would not be useful if the list had only three items, but the list could be a various number of sizes like 25 or 100).

Comment: You could always try it and time each method, but I'd bet a six pack you won't make a significantly faster method. Fundamentally it has to do nearly the same amount of work, you're just changing the order that it is creating them.

Comment: Generating two groups of three is going to take the same amount of time it takes to generate a single group of six. The code may be simpler, but not significant faster.

Comment: @CoryKramer I understand that it will not be that much faster for groups of three, but I intend to use it for a variety of list sizes. I'll add that information to my question.

Comment: As @CoryKramer pointed out already, you're probably not going to get anything significantly faster than the python builtin implementation. However, there might be other ways in which you could optimize the execution time of your program. Can you give us some more context? What do you want to achieve in the end? What are you using the permutations for?

Comment: @chepner To be more clear, I'm not trying to generate the given groups. I would like to generate any one of the given items from each group. So, I am looking for permutations but do not consider a list shifted over n times to be any different than one that is shifted over m times.

Comment: @Felix For my purposes, I have n points in a cartesian coordinate system. I would like to find the best route through each of the points such that the distance is minimized (starts and ends at same point). My way of doing so would be to generate every possible arrangement of cities and find the best route. Since the route starts and ends at the same point, the "starting point" city in a route doesn't matter, which is why I have the problem above. I understand this would take a ridiculous amount of computation time for large numbers, but for my intentions, that is fine.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have a computer science background, but what you're describing it known as the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms).

Your proposed solution is the "brute-force" algorithm and doen't scale to more than a couple of points. There are alternative algorithms that are more efficient. If you need to calculate the exact optimum, take a look at the `Exact Algorithms` section in the linked article. If a good solution is "good enough", you can also use heuristics to cut execution time.

Comment: Yeah. I created a genetic algorithm to approximate the best route to take and had an option to calculate the exact route as well in order to compare how well the genetic algorithm did compared to the actual result. I am looking into using a variation held-karp algorithm that is better optimized for the symmetric version of the traveling salesman problem. I found a source; however, my theoretical knowledge of CS is practically nothing, so I do not know how I would even begin to make code from the given paper: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01585505.pdf